# How to use the cl-pg package?

Tags: raspberry-pi, common-lisp, raspberry-pi4, clisp

I have installed clisp and cl-pg on my computer (Raspberry PI 4B) to work with PostGres from a Lisp script.

```
# apt install clisp
# apt install cl-pg
```

The few tricks I have tried starting with the example code given [here](https://pg.common-lisp.dev/) lead to nothing.

```
   (with-pg-connection (conn "testdb" "login" :host "dbhost" :password "secret")
      (with-pg-transaction conn
         (when (member "test_date" (pg-tables conn) :test #'string=)
            (pg-exec "DROP TABLE test_date"))
         (pg-exec conn "CREATE TABLE test_date(a timestamp, b abstime, c time, d date)")
         (pg-exec conn "INSERT INTO test_date VALUES "
                       "(current_timestamp, 'now', 'now', 'now')")))
```

Is there some sample code available somewhere showing how to use cl-pg, including any necessary (load ...) or whatever is needed to make use of this package ?

Comment: Did you dismiss the more known postmodern? http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/postmodern/ In Debian repos as `cl-postmodern`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is no wonder that it doesn't work, because you are at the wrong package.
https://pg.common-lisp.dev/ is pg-dot-list. not cl-pg.

It is however to be recommended to use `postmodern` for this purpose (more modern library):

```
(ql:quickload "postmodern")

;; https://github.com/marijnh/Postmodern

;; connect by:
(postmodern:connect-toplevel "testdb" "foucault" "surveiller" "localhost" :port 5434)

;; query by:
(postmodern:query "SQL query string")

;; at the end disconnect
(postmodern:disconnect-toplevel)
```

The package has also a `with-connection` macro:

```
(postmodern:with-connection '("testdb" "foucault" "surveiller" "localhost")
 (postmodern:query "SQL query string")
 ...)
```

Comment: @Gwang-Jin_Kim. I see. Thank you for the comment. I had been misslead by seeing in the
Features, this: "available in Debian as the cl-pg package."

Comment: @Gwang-Jin_Kim. I am now trying the code you suggest.
When I run this in the clisp interpreter:
(ql:quickload "cl-pg")
I get this error: 
*** - READ from #<INPUT CONCATENATED-STREAM #<INPUT STRING-INPUT-STREAM> #<IO TERMINAL-STREAM>>: there is no package with name "QL"
The following restarts are available: ...

Comment: @Gwang-Jin_Kim. I have somewhat solved the first problem by installing quicklisp. But, although I have installed cl-pg as written in my post, now when running (ql:quickload "cl-pg") I get this error: 
** - Continuable Error
System "cl-pg" not found
If you continue (by typing 'continue'): Try again
The following restarts are also available:
ABORT          :R1      Give up on "cl-pg"
REGISTER-LOCAL-PROJECTS :R2 Register local projects and try again.
ABORT          :R3      Abort main loop

Comment: @Michel - I edited. Use `postmodern`.